# Creating an SDL2 window in C via Python3 ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdl, ctypes

I want to create a small application using Python 3.3 and ctypes, in which the graphics and some other low level operations are done in a C shared library.  I have some SDL2 code to create a simple window that works fine when run as a standalone executable, but not when called via ctypes as a shared library.

SDL doesn't produce any errors when called via ctypes, but the window is simply never displayed.  I have to imagine this has something to do with threads or spawning processes, but searching hasn't netted me any results.

Comment: Can you have your shared library write to a log and make sure it is being called correctly?

Comment: @Alden Yes, I have several other functions that can write to files and print to stdout, and all work as expected.

Comment: Just to check, SDL_Init returns 0? Does your SDL instance report X,Y,W,H like you expect it to? And for kicks I would try SDL_FULLSCREEN just to make sure it didn't work.

Comment: @Alden Thanks for the tips.  SDL_Init is returning 0, and SDL_GetWindowSize gives the expected results.  When I switch the flag from SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN to SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN, my screen goes black as if something were about to display, but then the expected image is never shown.

Comment: Can you try using SDL_FillRect() and blit a color to the screen rather than an image?

Comment: @Alden I'm a bit new to SDL2, but I tried using the relatively straightforward example code [here](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_RenderPresent) and the results are the same.  If I build a proper executable, I get the red window.  If I call the same code via ctypes I get no display (or an empty, black fullscreen window).

Answer (score 1):

Your ctypes bindings might be wrong. Did you make sure that they correctly wrap the required functions of yours?

http://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2 seems to contain ctypes-wrappers for SDL2, which you might use as reference for your own code.